# Install Android app from a local server [No internet connection]

Tags: android

Is there any way to use a local server to send my app to the users connected to a LAN?(no internet available), but I don't want my users to download the APK and install it, I want to make the download like Google Play sort of way.

Thanks.

Update:
Ok, I don't want to make this without the user permission, I want to show them like a website(in the local server), and from there provide a link or a way to install my app (located in the local server as well), without sending the APK to the user, but installing the app.

This is because there's no internet in the place I want to use this.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You cannot force devices to install apps from remote, for blindingly obvious security reasons. The only reason why the Play Store can (sorta) do this is because the Play Store already is installed on the device, so it can watch for signals to install a new app or an update for an app.

You are welcome to write your own app (call it `LocalInstallerApp`) that goes on the devices, that monitors an internal server for apps to install or update. However:

- `LocalInstallerApp` would have to be installed manually, by downloading it from your server
- `LocalInstallerApp` will still need user approval to install new or updated apps; it cannot do those things silently (exceptions: if you build your own custom ROM or possibly if the device is rooted)